# How to push and clone yii2 projects to github?

Tags: github, yii2, composer-php

I have developed a simple web-app with yii2 and pushed it to my github repository. I tried to clone it to another folder and test it, but it didn't work.

Something tells me that it is because I get my yii2 from an archive without composer and when I try to clone it, I use composer install command to get vendor folder and autoload file and it doesn't do it right.

Why is it happening and how can I push my web-apps properly to github so that everyone can clone and start them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to see git commands and any errors or more information on how it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Once you've done the Yii2 app ready into you local, kindly follow below basic commands of Git.

**Git Basic Commands**

Git Checkout:

```
$ git clone CHECKOUT_URL
```

To check git files status:

```
$ git status
```

To add all file into git:

```
$ git add *
```

To add selected file into git:

```
$ git add filename1, filename2
```

To commit all added/updated/deleted files into Git:

```
$ git commit -m "initial commit" *
```

To commit selected file into git

```
$ git commit -m "initial commit" filename1, folder1
```

To push committed files into Git master branch:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

To see all exists branches:

```
$ git branch
```

To create new branch:

```
$ git branch changes
```

To select branch:

```
$ git checkout changes
```

To commit into selected branch “changes”:

```
 $ git push origin changes
```

**Other Git Commands:**

```
$ git --help
usage: git [--version] [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           [-c name=value] [--help]
           <command> [<args>]

The most commonly used git commands are:
   add        Add file contents to the index
   bisect     Find by binary search the change that introduced a bug
   branch     List, create, or delete branches
   checkout   Checkout a branch or paths to the working tree
   clone      Clone a repository into a new directory
   commit     Record changes to the repository
   diff       Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc
   fetch      Download objects and refs from another repository
   grep       Print lines matching a pattern
   init       Create an empty git repository or reinitialize an existing one
   log        Show commit logs
   merge      Join two or more development histories together
   mv         Move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink
   pull       Fetch from and merge with another repository or a local branch
   push       Update remote refs along with associated objects
   rebase     Forward-port local commits to the updated upstream head
   reset      Reset current HEAD to the specified state
   rm         Remove files from the working tree and from the index
   show       Show various types of objects
   status     Show the working tree status
   tag        Create, list, delete or verify a tag object signed with GPG
```